# Android Studio StackOverFlowError: null

Tags: android, android-studio, stack-overflow, android-studio-2.3

After updating to version 2.3 today, my Android Studio stopped working.

```
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:272)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:268)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:222)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.DocumentImpl.getText(DocumentImpl.java:806)
    at com.intellij.notification.EventLog.getStatusText(EventLog.java:279)
    at com.intellij.notification.EventLog.formatForLog(EventLog.java:178)
    at com.intellij.notification.LogModel.addNotification(LogModel.java:57)
    at com.intellij.notification.EventLog$ProjectTracker.printNotification(EventLog.java:507)
    at com.intellij.notification.EventLog$ProjectTracker.access$100(EventLog.java:462)
    at com.intellij.notification.EventLog$ProjectTracker$1.notify(EventLog.java:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:377)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:364)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:350)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:343)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.notify(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.notification.Notifications$Bus.doNotify(Notifications.java:75)
    at com.intellij.notification.Notifications$Bus.lambda$notify$1(Notifications.java:69)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.intellij.notification.Notifications$Bus.notify(Notifications.java:69)
    at com.intellij.notification.Notification.notify(Notification.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.addToEventLog(GradleSyncState.java:246)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.addInfoToEventLog(GradleSyncState.java:242)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncStarted(GradleSyncState.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncStarted(GradleSyncState.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.handlePreSyncCheckFailure(GradleSyncInvoker.java:207)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:179)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdk(SdkSync.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.syncIdeAndProjectAndroidSdks(SdkSync.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.doCheckCanSync(AndroidSdkPreSyncCheck.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.AndroidStudioSyncCheck.canSync(AndroidStudioSyncCheck.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.precheck.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$1(GradleSyncInvoker.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSyncAndSourceGeneration(GradleSyncInvoker.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.sdk.GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.afterSdkPathChange(GradleAndroidSdkEventListener.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.afterAndroidSdkPathUpdate(IdeSdks.java:316)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$null$0(SdkSync.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.lambda$setIdeSdk$1(SdkSync.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2432)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SdkSync.setIdeSdk(SdkSync.java:212)
```

The error message is too long, I cannot post all here. Anyone knows how to fix this please? And by the way I had to install the SDK from the android-sdk package, not included in the android-studio. I'm using Arch Linux x64.

Comment: Full error message here: http://pastebin.com/GBBP2Hnw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some manual tinkering, I found that it's because the new SDK and NDK were installed in /opt which is owned by root and my user have not right permissions.
And as many have mentioned, I had to link the libstdc++ from /usr/lib to /emulator/lib64/libstdc++

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade gradle version. Seems like it doesn't support old gradle anymore